# Supporting different AfterBuild behaviors in WiX 3.5

Tags: wix, windows-installer, target, conditional-statements

I've had absolutely no luck in finding information about supporting multiple conditions for a Target.  Specifically, depending upon the project configuration, I'd like `AfterBuild` to do different things.

For example, I want to run a batch a.bat if my project configuration is A, and b.bat if my project configuration is B.  My WiX project file has the following Targets:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='A'">
    <Exec Command="c:\installers\a.bat" />
</Target>
<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='B'">
    <Exec Command="c:\installers\b.bat" />
</Target>
```

Now the WiX experts here already know that this doesn't work.  While it *does* compile and execute, WiX will only respect the wishes of the last `AfterBuild` Target.  I looked around for information about using `<Condition>` within `Target`, but it looks like that's only valid for other elements.

Can anyone present the correct XML language for supporting multiple conditions in Targets?

**EDIT** -- perhaps the only answer is to pass $(Configuration) as an argument and then let the batch file sort things out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel stupid.  Not only is there a `Condition` attribute for `Target`, but you can also use it with `Exec` (and others like `Copy`, which I am using).  So you just have to put multiple `<Exec>` and `<Copy>` elements within the `AfterBuild` Target, and it works out.

Comment: Accept your answer for consistency

Comment: @Yan I would have, but have to wait 2 days from the posting time before I can do that.

Comment: @Yan nope... "You can accept your own answer in 23 hours
(click on this box to dismiss)"